# How can I declare and define multiple variables in one statement?

Tags: javascript

## What I have so far

This is what my code currently look like:

```js
var a, b, c = "hello world " + "I am here " + "my name is hamza";
```

## What my problem is

But only `c` is defined whereas `a` and `b` are `undefined`.

```js
a // returns: undefined
b // returns: undefined
c // returns: "hello world I am here my name is hamza"
```

## What I'd like to achieve

How can I have **all three variables defined** with each one of the three string literals **in a single statement**?

```
// How to do that in a single statement instead of three?
var a = "hello world";
var b = "I am here";
var c = "my name is hamza";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this what you wannna achieve.

```
var a = "hello world ", b =  "I am here" , c = "my name is hamza"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try *[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)*:

```
const [ a, b, c] = [ 'hello world', 'I am here', 'my name is hamza'];
```